# Wikipedia-API fallback if extract is empty

Tags: json, api, wikipedia, wiki

I am requesting data from Wikipedia API.
My request-URL looks like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages%7Cinfo&inprop=url&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=144&pilimit=50&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1n&generator=geosearch&ggscoord=47.073733%7C15.3918631&ggsradius=10000&ggslimit=50&origin=*

It returns pages located close to the given coordinates with their extract. But for some articles this extract is empty. Can you help me to extend my request to have either a fallback for an empty extract or to get the extract AND the first 10 sentences?

I don't want to request always the first 10 sentences, as the extract (if available) makes more sense.

Thank you